Is the game Settlers of Catan on-topic?
I recently saw the question How big is the sun (in the world of Catan)? which plays into something I long believed: that Catan was another world. That would make the game SFF-nal. But Wikipedia says something different (emphasis mine)

The players in the game represent settlers establishing settlements on the fictional island of Catan.

This assertion seems to be backed up by quotes from the game's author here: Is the Settlers of Catan board game based on or inspired by the settlers of Kataan planet in the Star Trek episode The Inner Light?
If Catan is merely an island, it lacks any other SFF-nal elements. It's a mere resource/community building game. There are SFF-nal variants, but that doesn't change the original game's backstory.
Is Catan about a planet or an island? Or is there some other SFF-nal element that makes it on-topic?

Hmm. Licenced expansion packs added dragons and other fantasy elements.

@Skooba - The licenced novel was absolutely full to the brim of people casting spells and doing magic, but I see no actual evidence that any of these spells resulted in a supernatural event occurring.

To answer the question if Catan is another world... it is not. From the Almanac of the Starfarers spin-off: "Humans found their first colonies during the 26th century. They are named Catanian Colonies, after an island in the Atlantic Ocean. Due to the growing population of Catanian Colonies, Earth's government decides to establish further colonies in planetary ssytems with uninhabited planets."

The novel and some expansions may have fantasy elements, but the base game does not, and therefore I think it's firmly off-topic. It's not enough that the island of Catan is fictional to make it a fantasy work.

I'm gonna say no. The original (1994/1995) game has relatively little by way of lore, mostly contained in the instruction manual which has this to say about the setting.

In Settlers of Catan, each player represents a group of settlers who
have landed on the remote island of Catan. The goal of the game is to
become the dominant group on the island by acquiring Victory Points.
Victory Points are earned by building settlements and cities, by
having the longest road or the largest army, or by purchasing certain
cards.

Nothing in the manual or box cover suggest that the setting is fantastical, or anything other than a sort of faux-medieval pastiche, with knights, robbers, sea-faring traders, etc.
The game also spawned an official novelisation of the base game. This contains a direct confirmation of the year in which the game is set, 850 A.D. This is also our own Earth, albeit a fictionalised version which contains a suspiciously large and empty island in the middle of the Atlantic.

The year is 850. In the seas of northern Europe, the small coastal
village of Elasund falls prey to marauding neighbors. Their food
stores pillaged, women and children stolen, livestock destroyed, the
villagers are left to barely survive the harsh winter — and
contemplate a drastic solution to their recurring hardships: leaving
the only village they have ever known. Foster brothers Candamir and
Osmund lead their people on an epic quest to a mythic island home, but
without knowledge of exactly where the island is, they must trust the
gods to deliver them safely. Lost at sea and set adrift, an
extraordinarily violent storm washes them ashore the island famed in
pagan lore: Catan.

The book itself contains ample references to magic and myth, but nothing that actually amounts to the supernatural. Anything the settlers don't understand (such as the healing power of herbs) is called out as magic, as are things that we would consider perfectly normal, such as the influence of a skilled speaker over others.

Candamir could no longer sit still. He stood up, folded his arms, and
looked down at Osmund, shaking his head. “So you think I’m so weak
that I’ve simply fallen under a magic spell, do you?”
“No, not weak, just gullible and good-natured. His magic is strong.
The very fact that so many of our people have been taken in by him—not
the least of whom is your wife, who has just as strong a will as you
do—proves that.”

and

A hush fell over the crowd as Inga entered the temple. She wore a robe
unlike anything they had seen before—a wide, blood red cloak with a
hood that completely shaded her face. Both were embroidered with magic
symbols, runes, and pentagrams. Her feet were bare, and the cloak came
down to her ankles. It was closed in front, but the neck was so large
that Candamir was not the only one to wonder whether she was wearing
anything underneath.


Later editions of the game are far more topical. The 2016 expansion pack TREASURES, DRAGONS & ADVENTURERS is an obvious example, adding magical flying dragons to the mix.

Desert Dragons
Peace and prosperity reign on Catan. However, this blessed state is
not going to last very long. Dragons are gathering in the desert, as
if magically attracted by the Health of the settlements and cities.
With each new settlement and each new city, the number of dragons
increases. Soon the wild hordes will leave the desert and attack
Catan. When this happens, all the Catanians can do is escape to the
uninhabited neighboring island in the Southeast, where they will have
the opportunity to gather strength and expel the dragons from their
homeland.

There was also a version set in spaaaaaaace!

Finally, a jump to the stars has succeeded! It is the middle of the
3rd millennium. You and your fellow Catanians travel in spaceships to
distant planetary systems in search of more resources.
Along the way, you befriend alien civilizations who might become
valued trading partners.


+1 "a sort of faux-medieval pastiche, with knights, robbers, sea-faring traders, etc." Don't forget colonizers displacing the indigenous people…

@Lexible - That never happens in real life. Fake news.

I direct your attention to the artwork on the Seafarers of Catan. :)

If the creators say it's about an island, not about another world, then we take their word for it.  It's really the only thing we can do.  (Besides it makes sense; there's no reason to require it to be on another world; it's a "least [conceptual] effort" thing.)
At that point it's down to only SFnal aspects of the game (if any) being on-topic, or as you note, SF-based variants.

Could the Starfarers spin-off retroactively make the entire franchise on-topic since the space travels are descended from the original?  Or would you stick with only that version is on-topic?

@Skooba Precedent would suggest the latter.  If we consider the equivalent in a novel series, if the first four books are pure historical fiction and then the fifth introduces a character with magic, it doesn't change the first four.  This is also how ISFDb categorizes genre work, but I can't think of an example off the top of my head.  (I've seen a couple, but don't recall who the authors were.)

@Skooba - Baywatch Nights had vampires. That doesn't make the original Baywatch on-topic.

@Valorum Yup, I've been convinced it is off-topic.

@Skooba - On reflection, I'd like more Baywatch questions. I may need to rethink my answer :-)

@Valorum that's a different type of fantasy. Although you might convince me that the jiggle has some supernatural power behind it.

Shouldn't that be "SF-al" not "SF-nal"?

@Lexible It's hard to render in plain text, but a raised "n" with a bar under it is a common shorthand abbreviation for "[ai]tion" at the end of a word.  So "function" would be "func^n."  (Or perhaps I should say it's an abbrev^n.)  From which we get "func^{nal}" for "functional" and thus similarly for "ficitional."

Thank you, @DavidW! That convention makes sense now. :)

I think the original core game "Settlers of Catan", which the question is about, is off-topic.
It has no scifi or fantasy elements. The island is fictional, yes, but this isn't enough to characterize it as fantasy (otherwise any "historical" novel with fictional people or events would be a fantasy).
There might be fantasy or scifi elements to the novel (I haven't read it, I defer to people who have) or some of the expansions. That would make them, and not the original game, on-topic. The question should be about them if it wants to remain on-topic.
As it is now, this looks awfully close to a real-world question, which wouldn't be allowed here: "why does the Sun look so big in this drawing, is it a mistake or do real-world optics allow it?".

re: the last sentence regarding real-world science.... the close reason for that states: "Note that asking for an answer within the context of a fictional universe, even if that question requires real-world science information, is on-topic." So if in general Catan was considered on-topic there is nothing wrong with it, IMO.  -- However,I understand the argument saying the original Catan is not on-topic as it is not SFF.

@Skooba yes, agreed.

The novel had a bunch of people doing spells and magic, but it's the same as magic in our own world, a bunch of mumbo-jumbo that amounts to nothing in particular.
